# Should this be 慢慢地？

Tags: grammar

然後再慢慢的完成你的夢想，好嗎？
Should this be 慢慢地？Can verbs come after 的？
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRBnLDW4iVM
2:29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, grammatically it should be '地'. However, as long as it doesn't cause a major misunderstanding, people are paying less and less attention to this '的地得' problem in everyday use.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.